# eCommerce tools/sandbox

Tags: e-commerce, edi, b2b, cxml

This may be vague but hopefully someone can help me refine the question, but what I am looking for is perhaps ways/tools which I can test ecommerce/b2b functionality, like punching out using cXML, creating EDI documents, and testing them in a (ideally free for development)sandbox.  Can anyone suggest anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In other words, you're looking for a free (ideally) data translator.

You could download the Jitterbit Community Edition ([Jitterbit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jitterbit/files/))

You could also use BOTS for EDI: [BOTS](http://bots.sourceforge.net/en/index.shtml)

Or Talend ([Talend](http://www.talend.com/products/data-integration))

Without knowing full scope of what you're trying to do, it's hard to point in the right direction.  If you want a commercial data translator that you plan on building out an integration architecture, look at Liaison's Delta and ECS ([Liaison](http://www.liaison.com))